# How to get a random float number between 0 and 1 for batch script?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, cmd.exe

I need to get a random float number between 0 and 1 (probability) to feed into
my batch script.

It seems %RANDOM% only returns integers? 
I tried dividing by max number (around 32000) and I just get back an int.

Answer (score 1):

Batch files do not support floating point arithmetic. There are some possible workarounds discussed in a few answers to these questions on StackOverflow:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503888/floating-point-division-in-a-batch-file
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217965/how-to-assign-a-floating-point-number-to-a-variable-in-cmd
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689450/decimals-in-batch-script